# kohana validation rule versus language file

Tags: php, internationalization, kohana

i have a kohana powered website and i use a language file for language messages.
in the model i do validation, and i have a 'matches' rule. here is one:

```
    ->rule('email2',  'matches', array('email');
```

and in the languge file i do:

```
   'email2.matches' => 'message here.',
```

but i get the error message: E-mail: must be the same as E-mail: instead of 'message here.'.

where i am wrong? is this thing documented ?

thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Validation errors use messages, which are separate from i18n. You will need to make your own `messages/validation.php`, and include

```
<?php

return array(
    'email2' => array(
        'matches' => 'Message here',
    ),
);
```